# Deserialize Actor in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

From this Akka Serialization documentation http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/serialization.html

On the part of serializing actor, I find this to deserialize:

```
val deserializedActorRef = extendedSystem.provider.resolveActorRef(identifier)
```

However when I tried that with my ActorSystem that I created like:

```
val extendedSystem = ActorSystem("myactorsystem")
```

I got this message:

> method provider in trait ActorRefFactory cannot be accessed in
>   akka.actor.ActorSystem
>
> Access to protected method provider not permitted because
>   enclosing class *ClassName* in package *PackageName* is not a
>   subclass of trait ActorRefFactory in package actor where
>   target is defined

Is there anything that I should do before I can use the resolveActorRef function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the some issue. I'm guessing that in the documentation they were trying to say to use `ExtendedActorSystem` instead of `ActorSystem` (as the name `extendedSystem`implies) and then ExtendedActorSystem has public access to provider. I haven't found a way how to use it so I found a workaround using `SerializationExtension`:

```
val system = ActorSystem("myactorsystem")
val serialization = SerializationExtension(system)
val deserializedActorRef = serialization.system.provider.resolveActorRef(actorRef)
```

I hope it helps.